# Change links into anchor links on load with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dom, hyperlink

I am trying to set up my webpage so that the HTML has normal links and then they change to anchor links on DOM ready.

So far i've had no luck, i'm still relatively new to using regular expressions so I have mos probably tried doing it all wrong.

Heres my jQuery code:

```
    $(".LINKS").each(function() {

        $(this).attr(
            "src",
            $(this).attr("src",replace('/\/\?page\=*?/ig', "/#"))
        );


    });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is a "normal link"?

Comment: has link to pages (ie /?page=test) and want to transform theses to anchor links (ie /#test)

Comment: first of all - the "src" attribute belongs to images, not anchors (links)... second of all, you're replacing stuff simply with "/#", which certainly does not work... can't look into it now but try working along these lines... and lastly - better use $('a.LINKS') selector, it will perform faster ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Links in html are done with an `href` attribute on the `a` node, not an `src`. `src` is for image url in `img` nodes.

```
$(".LINKS").each(function() {
    $(this).attr(
        "href",
        $(this).attr("href",replace('/\/\?page\=*?/ig', "/#"))
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides the other guys' comments about "href", you have specified a STRING rather than a REGULAR EXPRESSION:

```
replace('/\/\?page\=*?/ig', "/#")
```

should be:

```
replace(/\/\?page\=*?/ig, "/#")
```

i.e. get rid of the apostrophes surrounding the first argument.